# Unable to use saved model as starting point for training Baselines' MlpPolicy?

Tags: python, tensorflow, restore, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm currently using code from OpenAI baselines to train a model, using the following code in my `train.py`:

```
from baselines.common import tf_util as U
import tensorflow as tf
import gym, logging

from visak_dartdeepmimic import VisakDartDeepMimicArgParse

def train(env, initial_params_path,
        save_interval, out_prefix, num_timesteps, num_cpus):
    from baselines.ppo1 import mlp_policy, pposgd_simple
    sess = U.make_session(num_cpu=num_cpus).__enter__()

    U.initialize()

    def policy_fn(name, ob_space, ac_space):
        print("Policy with name: ", name)
        policy = mlp_policy.MlpPolicy(name=name, ob_space=ob_space, ac_space=ac_space,
            hid_size=64, num_hid_layers=2)
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        if initial_params_path is not None:
            print("Tried to restore from ", initial_params_path)
            saver.restore(tf.get_default_session(), initial_params_path)
        return policy

    def callback_fn(local_vars, global_vars):
        iters = local_vars["iters_so_far"]
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        if iters % save_interval == 0:
            saver.save(sess, out_prefix + str(iters))

    pposgd_simple.learn(env, policy_fn,
            max_timesteps=num_timesteps,
            callback=callback_fn,
            timesteps_per_actorbatch=2048,
            clip_param=0.2, entcoeff=0.0,
            optim_epochs=10, optim_stepsize=3e-4, optim_batchsize=64,
            gamma=1.0, lam=0.95, schedule='linear',
        )
    env.close()
```

Which is based off of the code that OpenAI itself provides [in the baselines repository](https://github.com/openai/baselines/blob/master/baselines/ppo1/run_humanoid.py)

This works fine, except that I get some pretty weird looking learning curves which I suspect are due to some hyperparameters passed to the `learn` function which cause performance to decay / high variance as things go on (though I don't know for certain)

[image]

Anyways, to confirm this hypothesis I'd like to retrain the model but not from scratch: I'd like to start it off from a high point: say, iteration 1600 for which I have a saved model lying around (having saved it with `saver.save` in `callback_fn`

So now I call the `train` function, but this time I provide it with an `inital_params_path` pointing to the save prefix for iteration 1600. By my understanding, the call to `saver.restore` in `policy_fn` should restore "reset" the model to where it was at 1teration 1600 (and I've confirmed that the load routine runs using the print statement)

However, in practice I find that it's almost like nothing gets loaded. For instance, if I got statistics like

```
----------------------------------
| EpLenMean       | 74.2         |
| EpRewMean       | 38.7         |
| EpThisIter      | 209          |
| EpisodesSoFar   | 662438       |
| TimeElapsed     | 2.15e+04     |
| TimestepsSoFar  | 26230266     |
| ev_tdlam_before | 0.95         |
| loss_ent        | 2.7640965    |
| loss_kl         | 0.09064759   |
| loss_pol_entpen | 0.0          |
| loss_pol_surr   | -0.048767302 |
| loss_vf_loss    | 3.8620138    |
----------------------------------
```

for iteration 1600, then for iteration 1 of the new trial (ostensibly using 1600's parameters as a starting point), I get something like

```
----------------------------------
| EpLenMean       | 2.12         |
| EpRewMean       | 0.486        |
| EpThisIter      | 7676         |
| EpisodesSoFar   | 7676         |
| TimeElapsed     | 12.3         |
| TimestepsSoFar  | 16381        |
| ev_tdlam_before | -4.47        |
| loss_ent        | 45.355236    |
| loss_kl         | 0.016298374  |
| loss_pol_entpen | 0.0          |
| loss_pol_surr   | -0.039200217 |
| loss_vf_loss    | 0.043219414  |
----------------------------------
```

which is back to square one (this is around where my models trained from scratch start)

The funny thing is I know that the model is being saved properly at least, since I can actually replay it using `eval.py`

```
from baselines.common import tf_util as U
from baselines.ppo1 import mlp_policy, pposgd_simple
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

class PolicyLoaderAgent(object):
    """The world's simplest agent!"""
    def __init__(self, param_path, obs_space, action_space):
        self.action_space = action_space

        self.actor = mlp_policy.MlpPolicy("pi", obs_space, action_space,
                                        hid_size = 64, num_hid_layers=2)
        U.initialize()
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        saver.restore(tf.get_default_session(), param_path)

    def act(self, observation, reward, done):
        action2, unknown = self.actor.act(False, observation)
        return action2


if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = VisakDartDeepMimicArgParse()
    parser.add_argument("--params-prefix", required=True, type=str)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    env = parser.get_env()

    U.make_session(num_cpu=1).__enter__()

    U.initialize()

    agent = PolicyLoaderAgent(args.params_prefix, env.observation_space, env.action_space)

    while True:
        ob = env.reset(0, pos_stdv=0, vel_stdv=0)
        done = False
        while not done:
            action = agent.act(ob, reward, done)
            ob, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
            env.render()
```

and I can clearly see that its learned something as compared to an untrained baseline. The loading action is the same across both files (or rather, if there's a mistake there then I can't find it), so it appears probable to me that `train.py` is correctly loading the model and then, due to something in the [`pposdg_simple.learn` function's](https://github.com/openai/baselines/blob/master/baselines/ppo1/pposgd_simple.py), promptly forgets about it.

Could anyone shed some light on this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is still relevant since the baselines repository has changed quite a bit since this question was posted, but it seems that you are not actually initialising the variables before restoring them. Try moving the call of `U.initialize()` inside your `policy_fn`:

```
def policy_fn(name, ob_space, ac_space):
    print("Policy with name: ", name)    
    policy = mlp_policy.MlpPolicy(name=name, ob_space=ob_space, 
                                  ac_space=ac_space, hid_size=64, num_hid_layers=2)
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    if initial_params_path is not None:  
        print("Tried to restore from ", initial_params_path)
        U.initialize()
        saver.restore(tf.get_default_session(), initial_params_path)
    return policy
```